# Clear button on UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield, uitextview

How can I add a clear button (cross inside a circle) for UITextView like UITextField has?

Comment: I am doing it thru XCODE. What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just make a uibutton and put it on uitextview and set its action for clear text view;

```
uitextview.frame = (0,0,320,416);

uibutton.frame = (310,0,10,10);
[uibutton setimage:@"cross.png" forcontrolstate:uicontrolstatenoraml];
[uibutton addTarget:self action:@selector(clearButtonSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)clearButtonSelected{
    uitextview=@"";
}
```

hope you want to clear the text view text when you click on cross button above is help
if not understand then i can send you proper program for that

Comment: run into the same need, where to get this cross.png?

Answer (score 11):

Based on the answer from GhostRider a more accurate and up to date implementation:

```
int kClearButtonWidth = 15;
int kClearButtonHeight = kClearButtonWidth;

//add the clear button
self.clearButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.clearButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UITextFieldClearButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.clearButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UITextFieldClearButtonPressed.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

self.clearButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, kClearButtonWidth, kClearButtonHeight);
self.clearButton.center = CGPointMake(self.textView.frame.size.width - kClearButtonWidth , kClearButtonHeight);

[self.clearButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clearTextView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.textView addSubview:self.clearButton];
```

And the method

```
- (void)clearTextView:(id)sender{
    self.textView.text = @"";
}
```

You can use this images for the two states of the button:

[image: UITextFieldButton]
[image: UITextFieldButtonPressed]

Comment: A perfect answer, but with XCode 6's insistance on using AutoLayout, I had to give up on creating the button programmatically, as you must add Constraints to ensure it does appear in the right place.  In the end, I added a UIButton directly on the Storyboard, and added constraints there instead.  (Sigh...)

Answer (score 4):

From product perspective, if you're going to have a clear button, you probably want to use a `UITextField` instead of a `UITextView` and `UITextField` supports a clear button natively - set the `clearButtonMode` property as such:

```
UITextField *textfield = ...;
textfield.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

See screenshot:

[image]

You could use `UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing` to only present the clear button while the user is actively updating the content.

Comment: (Sigh.) The question was how to add a Clear button to a UITextView (not a UITextField)... and that DOESN'T have a ClearButtonMode member function...!!

Comment: @Mike Gledhill, just updated the answer to address your comment, I think for something like clearing a `UITextView` you are better off with a clear button (i.e. `UIButton`). I just don't see how an X clear button would work with multi-line text views.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing built in like there is for the UITextField. You'd have to add the view yourself (probably a UIButton) and place it correctly and also somehow get the text to wrap around it correctly. (And I don't think the latter is really possible.)

Maybe instead you should display a toolbar above the keyboard (or an [`inputAccessoryView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006898-CH3-SW21) if you're targeting 3.2 and later) that provides a clear button.

Comment: I agree. Apple must have its reason not adding clear button in TextView. For example, if there are long multiple lines of text, user may have to scroll up to the top to find the clear button. Adding a clear or "select all" button outside of TextView or on toolbar may be the best choice. Just follow Apple's UI guideline.

Answer (score 0):

For me changing the .frame or the .contentInset properties did not work.

For me the best result came from:

1) adding a UIView to the controller, give it round corners and a border to mimic a UITextView.

```
self.viewTextBackground.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:171/255.0 green:171/255.0 blue:171/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
self.viewTextBackground.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
self.viewTextBackground.layer.cornerRadius = 9.0f;
```

2) place UITextView on top of this UIView. Place it so that the borders of the underlying UIView stay visible.

3) give the UITextView round corners:

```
self.textNote.layer.cornerRadius = 9.0f;
```

3) Make its width fe. 30pixels less compared to the underlying UIView. You now have space for a clear-button.

4) simply add a UIButton to your controller and place it in the top-right corner of the underlying UIView.

5) change the buttons properties: set its type to 'custom' and set its image to the image of a grey cross.

6) bind an action to the button te clear the UITextView

Answer (score 0):

You can add a clear button like the one in the attached screenshot with minimal coding. Just follow these steps:

- Select the storyboard and drag a UIButton into your UITextView
- Set the buttons constraints
- Assign a title or a background image
- Create the button's IBOutlet reference and the action (see `onClearPressed(_:)` below) for "Touch Up Inside" in the ViewController
- Implement the `textViewDidChange(_:) UITextViewDelegate` delegate method, and make sure to set the button's isEnabled property based on the textfield content, e.g.:

`func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    clearButton.isEnabled = !textView.text.isEmpty
}`

- Implement the `onClearPressed(_:)` action:

`@IBAction func onClearPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    textView.text = ""
    clearButton.isEnabled = false
}`

That's it.

[image: clear button in UTextView]

Answer (score 0):

Here is custom textView with clear button:

```
final class ClearableTextView: UITextView {
    
    private lazy var clearButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "clear.fill"), for: .normal)
        button.setTitle(nil, for: .normal)
        button.tintColor = .gray
        addSubview(button)
        return button
    } ()
    let clearButtonSize: CGFloat = 30
    let clearButtonRightInset: CGFloat = 4
    
    
    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            clearButton.frame = CGRect(
                x: bounds.maxX - clearButtonSize - clearButtonRightInset,
                y: bounds.midY - clearButtonSize / 2,
                width: clearButtonSize,
                height: clearButtonSize
            )
        }
    }
    
    public override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        setup()
    }
    
    public required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super .init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }
    
    private func setup() {
        clearButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onClearClick), for: .touchUpInside)
        textContainerInset.right = clearButtonSize + clearButtonRightInset
    }
    
    @objc private func onClearClick() {
        text = nil
        delegate?.textViewDidChange?(self)
    }
}
```