# TextView - where's the "clear when editing begins" option?

Tags: cocoa-touch, textview, textfield

TextFields have this very useful option, "clear when editing begins", but can't seem to find it in TextViews. Is there an equivalent? If not what is the approved work around?

Comment: Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877980/clear-button-on-uitextview

Comment: No, I don't think I've explained my self clearly enough and I didn't find that example was the answer. In a textView I have some initial text like "Type here to enter your message..." When the user taps on it the initial message disappears. TextFields have that option and I'm slightly baffled as to why TextViews don't as well...

Answer (score 0):

Then you should create a custom TextView subclass. You can find one [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328638/placeholder-in-uitextview)