# How to Add a Button to CLEAR a UITextView?

Tags: uitextview, xcode4.5

I have a UITextView and need to add a CLEAR button below it such that when it is pressed it will clear that UITextView.

Not understanding how to connect the two elements or create a delegate in ObjC.
Can do it in VisualBasic.

Thank you.

Comment: you have iVar for your textview and method for buttn pressed event in your class?

Comment: Look at this answer... Works perfectly!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877980/clear-button-on-uitextview/

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom textView with clear button:

```
final class ClearableTextView: UITextView {
    
    private lazy var clearButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "clear.fill"), for: .normal)
        button.setTitle(nil, for: .normal)
        button.tintColor = .gray
        addSubview(button)
        return button
    } ()
    let clearButtonSize: CGFloat = 30
    let clearButtonRightInset: CGFloat = 4
    
    
    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            clearButton.frame = CGRect(
                x: bounds.maxX - clearButtonSize - clearButtonRightInset,
                y: bounds.midY - clearButtonSize / 2,
                width: clearButtonSize,
                height: clearButtonSize
            )
        }
    }
    
    public override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        setup()
    }
    
    public required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super .init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }
    
    private func setup() {
        clearButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onClearClick), for: .touchUpInside)
        textContainerInset.right = clearButtonSize + clearButtonRightInset
    }
    
    @objc private func onClearClick() {
        text = nil
        delegate?.textViewDidChange?(self)
    }
}
```